# ios opengles present render buffer to view when UIView drawing cause app crash

Tags: ios, uiview, opengl-es, crash

I'm writing a opengl es app for ios. I created a thread for EAGLContext, do all the opengl stuff on this thread, then when it's done, present the render buffer to screen by using `performSelectorOnMainThread` and `presentRenderbuffer`.

The thing is, if no other UIView on top of my opengl view, everything is fine, but if a add a view on top of my opengl view, thing start to get unstable. Sometime if the UIView is animating, it will cause the opengl call crash, sometime crash at `glClear`, sometimes `presentRenderbuffer`. Things are particularly bad on iphone 6 plus, I guess because it has bigger screen resolution.

So, am I doing something wrong or I can only stop opengl rendering when UIView animating to prevent my app from crash?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a few things wrong here but I guess it should work...

The context is bound to the thread so the minimum you need is to set the context as current on the main thread before presenting the render buffer.

The main problem you are facing here though is that if you are presenting the buffer on a separate thread then it is possible that your background thread has already continued with the drawing and if for instance the first call is to clear the buffer then the buffer might already be cleared on the main thread.

So you will need some kind of locking mechanism or double buffering. You need to consider which is your main thread for openGL and rather create a context on that thread and set it as current. Then create another thread with shared context which is used on the secondary thread (it really should make no difference which is which, just define one as a "master" from which you can create other shared contexts). Now when the drawing thread is done with drawing the buffer you should notify the main thread that it can present the buffer (calling `performSelectorOnMainThread` should do), the main thread should then take that buffer and then present it. After it is done doing so it should notify back the drawing thread that it is ready to collect a new buffer.

So if you created double buffering then the pipeline would be something like that:

- Drawing thread draws to buffer 1
- Drawing buffer reports drawing ended and swaps the drawing buffer and continues to draw to buffer 2
- Presenting thread takes (locks) the buffer 1 and starts presenting it
- Now the buffer 2 might be already finished but presenting the buffer 1 is still locked so you need to choose either to discard the content of buffer 2 and draw to it again in hope the next cycle the buffer 1 will be unlocked. But in any case you may not swap the buffers
- After the buffer 1 is presented notify (unlock) buffer 1 on presenting thread and report the unlocking to the drawing thread. (reporting is not needed if you chose to redraw the buffer 2)
- When you are notified that the buffer 1 is unlocked and the contents of buffer 2 are already drawn simply swap the buffers and notify the presenting thread to present the buffer 2
- (OR) When you are done with drawing to buffer 2 again check if the buffer 1 is unlocked and swap the buffers and again notify the presenting thread to present the buffer 2
- Repeat the cycle with drawing to buffer 1...

Comment: Wow! Thanks for advice man! I will try to implement this double buffer method, and let you know how it works out

Comment: Hey Matic, in ios, I need to call `[EAGLContext renderbufferStorage]` on the main render buffer. When I'm implementing double buffer, if I  create 2 buffer for drawing, I need to call `renderbufferStorage` on both of them. So what I'm doing now is, create 2 complete fbo, on the rendering thread, before I start to draw, I bind the front fbo, call `renderbufferStorage` on it's render buffer, then draw. After done drawing, I switch fbo, push the old fron buffer to main thread, the do the presenting. So which means I need to call `renderbufferStorage` every frame, does this sound right to you?

Comment: No I think you should only call it twice if possible in loading time. I am not sure that works though. renderbufferStorage actually generates the render buffer so you would need to delete the previous one. Please do try just initialize both on the main thread in the beginning.

Comment: does it has to be main thread? I initialize both of them on my render thread, and the second buffer `renderbufferStorage ` failed

Comment: I would do that on the main thread. If possible simply create your main context on the main thread, then create the 2 buffers and initialize your background thread and pass the 2 buffers to it along with the shared context you create on the main thread from the main context. I am not sure about the pipeline of the renderbufferStorage but since it is working with the UIView I would say always do it on the main thread, even if it would work on the background thread you can never be sure it will keep working on the background thread.

Comment: Where exactly does it fail? I honestly haven't tried this shortcut yet, I usually redraw the textures to the main buffer. That means you only creat one view from drawable and attach textures to the 2 FBOs and use the textures when presenting the render buffer on the main thread. Also explain how you do the attachments, you might need 2 frame buffers in your shortcut situation...

Comment: I created 2 frame buffer, each has its own render buffer. `renderbufferStorage ` return YES on the first render buffer, return NO on second, and after that the status of the second frame buffer returns `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT`

Comment: I would need to see the code for that. It makes no sense the attachment is incomplete unless the wrong buffers are bound or one of the buffers failed to be created overall. Check the id of the failing buffer or some other data. It might be more appropriate to move this conversation to more personal means.. You can find my email on my profile page.